# How do you transfer between three eagles?

Tags: ski-safari

My last achievement is to transfer between three eagles as Bing Sven.
How do you do it?

Comment: Could you tell us what you've already tried?

Comment: Tried starting with an eagle from the cabin. Then flying at cloud level to the next eagle but they're hard to catch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main thing to realise here is that you don't have to catch the next eagle in the air.
Once on the ground avoid other animals until you can catch the next eagle.

Comment: This worked, achievement unlocked

Answer (score 3):

First of all, many people think that this is like bat transfer and you can exchange eagles in air ... *This is absolutely wrong*.

The fact here that if you land from the eagle, you can ski for some distance and ride an eagle again (Just try to avoid animals in the way) and also hitting obstacles when you are skiing doesn't reset the challenge.

Here's the thing: You will have 2 main problems:

1. Finding an Eagle
2. Catching an Eagle

First of all: Begin with the Eagle as the starting animal and activate super Eagle then start flying (Hitting obstacles while you fly resets the mission but hitting obstacles while skiing doesn't reset it).

You should fly in air in horizontal level or cloud level. After the lifetime of the Eagle ends you should now have an eagle in front of you and an eagle behind you. Catching the one in front of you is very hard so you should bury your head in the snow several times until the eagle behind you re-appears. Now it's your chance catch him.

Here are some tips for catching:

1. Never flip while in air, you will never catch him.
2. Adjust your landing style (Let him lean forward not backward) i.e: Don't press on the screen while flying
3. At some points Eagles can be caught on ground, make use of this critical chance.
4. You will be very lucky, if you catched the second eagle before landing from the first eagle. (Make use of this levels)
5. At some critical points, you will be facing the Eagle just infront of you but it will be faster (Use the super blue boost which can be bought from the shop)
6. When you use the blue boost, use it on the third eagle not the second because the third one is always hard and needs the blue boost.

I have been three hours doing this sh*t and it was my last challenge and finally did it, hope you guys do it too. You won't succeed from the first time. It's just a matter of trial and error. You will restart and restart and restart until you do it. Hoped I helped :)

Answer (score 1):

I followed the directions on [this forum post](http://www.chaptercheats.com/qna/iphone-ipod/104784/Ski-Safari-Answers.htm?qid=31678)

In summary: To setup turn off super eagle, select Eagle Bluffs, and select the eagle as your starting animal. Then, from the home screen, wait for an eagle to fly by before pressing the ski button. You'll start out with one eagle and then quickly transfer to the second eagle. Getting the third is tricky, hopefully you can catch one after a hill or two. If not, just avoid all other animals until the third eagle. Just keep going back to the start of the game until it works.

Answer (score 0):

Since no one here knows how the easiest way is , here it is, Once you start the level wait for an eagle to show up before you hit go or whatever, then try to hit the first eagle right out at the gate, immediately after you hit him hit the pause button and return to the main menu.  ( You have gotten 1 eagle already) then redo the same steps 3 times.